# Power Query - Group/ Unpivot List based on two conditions

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a huge list that contains such a kind of information:

[image]

Now I would like to group/ unpivot this list to get per Order Number

- the Max Sales Value based on Key 1 = 70 and Key 2 = 10 and
- the Max Sales Value based on Key 1 = 70 and Key 2 = 20

The result would be like that:

[image]

How is this possible by using Power Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjQwUNJRMgURhhCWgVKsDkzcDEQYgQgTFHFzuHoLHOLmphjiRhATYeKGOOw1xGGvIQ57DXHYa4hiL1h9LAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Order Number" = _t, #"Key 1" = _t, #"Key 2" = _t, #"Sales Value" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Order Number", Int64.Type}, {"Key 1", Int64.Type}, {"Key 2", Int64.Type}, {"Sales Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Key 1", type text}, {"Key 2", type text}}, "de-CH"),{"Key 1", "Key 2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Merged Columns", each ([Merged] = "7010" or [Merged] = "7020")),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Merged]), "Merged", "Sales Value", List.Max)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Output:**

[image]